# Angular cli build with sourceMap with option hidden

Tags: angular, angular-cli, hidden, source-maps

I want to build Angular with sourceMap, but without map file reference, so a hidden option must be set in [angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration)
but a json file is not flexible, I want to set it as command line parameter, just as

```
ng build --source-map=true/false
```

It seems like sourceMap can only set to true/false.

Is there any way to pass a object value to commmand-line parameter? like:

```
ng build --source-map=scripts:true,hidden:true
```

Comment: @NarenMurali https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration   of course Angular can do that.

Comment: [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NarenMurali It seems that the question is clear now.